# Array to string conversion (searching in codeigniter)

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I have problem with searching in my script. Problem is that i want to create filter. Filter is dropdown menu and i am entering data from this dropdown menu to array. I think this is problem but idk how to enter it different way.

Or how to pass data from my model as array and not as obj. (I think it is object)

My search:

```
          <?php echo form_open("otk/triedit", 'class="form-inline"'); ?>
          <th scope="col"></th>
          <th scope="col">ČÍSLO ZÁKAZKY</th>
          <th scope="col"><?php echo form_dropdown(['class' => 'form-control', 'name' => 'p'], $pozicia); ?>POZÍCIA</th>
          <th scope="col"><?php echo form_dropdown(['class' => 'form-control', 'name' => 's'], $stav); ?>STAV</th>
          <th scope="col">PORADOVÉ ČÍSLO</th>
          <th scope="col"><?php echo form_dropdown(['class' => 'form-control', 'name' => 'st'], $technologia); ?>TECHNOLÓGIA</th>
          <th scope="col"><?php echo form_dropdown(['class' => 'form-control', 'name' => 'd'], $datum); ?>DÁTUM</th>
          <th scope="col">DOKUMENT</th>
          <th scope="col"><?php echo form_dropdown(['class' => 'form-control', 'name' => 'z'], $zariadenie); ?>ZARIADENIE</th>
          <th scope="col">OPERÁTOR</th>
          <th scope="col"><center></center></th>
          <?php echo form_submit(['type' => 'submit', 'class' => 'btn btn-warning', 'value' => 'Hľadať']); ?>
          <?php echo form_close(); ?>
```

My Controller:

```
function triedit()
    {
        $this->load->model('base_model');

    $udaje = array(
        'hladat' => $this->input->post('p'),
        'hladat' => $this->input->post('s'),
        'hladat' => $this->input->post('st'),
        'hladat' => $this->input->post('d'), 
        'hladat' => $this->input->post('z')
    );

    $keyword    =   $udaje;
    $data['resulte']    =   $this->base_model->triedit($keyword);
    $this->load->view('base_triedit_view',$data);
}
```

My model:

```
function triedit($keyword)
    {
        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->from('otk');
        $this->db->like('ckod_otk',$keyword);
        $this->db->join('technologia', 'technologia.id_technologia = otk.technologia_otk', 'left');
        $this->db->join('zariadenie', 'zariadenie.id_zariadenie = otk.zariadenie_otk', 'left');
        $this->db->join('zamestnanci', 'zamestnanci.id_zamestnanci = otk.operator_otk', 'left');
        $this->db->join('stav', 'stav.id_stav = otk.stav_otk', 'left');
        $query  =   $this->db->get();
        return $query->num_rows();
    }
```

And my preview of my view:

```
<?php if(is_array($resulte)): ?>
        <?php 
            foreach ($resulte as $row) {?>
        <tr>
          <td></td>
          <td><?php echo $row->czakazky_otk; ?></td>
          <td><?php echo $row->pozicia_otk; ?></td>
          .....
          <?php } ?>
     <?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*as far as i understand your problem*

Data options format for `form_dropdown` is always in an `array` there is no alternative if you use  `form_dropdown`

If you want your model should return data as an array

Do it like this :

```
function triedit($keyword)
{
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('otk');
    $this->db->like('ckod_otk',$keyword);
    $this->db->join('technologia', 'technologia.id_technologia = otk.technologia_otk', 'left');
    $this->db->join('zariadenie', 'zariadenie.id_zariadenie = otk.zariadenie_otk', 'left');
    $this->db->join('zamestnanci', 'zamestnanci.id_zamestnanci = otk.operator_otk', 'left');
    $this->db->join('stav', 'stav.id_stav = otk.stav_otk', 'left');
    $query = $this->db->get();
    if ($query->num_rows() > 0 )
    {
       return $query->result_array();
    }
}
```

So changes in the view :

```
<?php if(is_array($resulte)): ?>

<?php 
    foreach ($resulte as $row) {?>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td><?php echo $row['czakazky_otk']; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $row['pozicia_otk']; ?></td>
      ..............
<?php } ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

For more : https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/results.html#result-arrays